# Where to set CRS property in react-leaflet?

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, react

I am changing my reference system in my Leaflet app. I am using the react-leaflet library since I am building it with React.

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, ImageOverlay, useMap } from 'react-leaflet'
import {CRS} from 'leaflet';

function App() {
  const center = [10.6952, 122.5705]
  const bounds = [[4.625, 126.575], [21.025, 116.975]];

  return (
  <MapContainer 
      center={center} 
      zoom={6} 
      scrollWheelZoom={true}
      crs={CRS.EPSG4326}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    <ImageOverlay
      url={example_solar_pv}
      bounds={bounds}
      opacity={0.5}
      zIndex={10}
    />
  </MapContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I place the property in the MapContainer, I get this result:
[image]

My map has a gray area. When I place the property in my TileLayer Component, my ImageLayer does not get bound properly.

[image]

Where should I place the property so that my Map would be in EPSG4326 since it is the reference system of my image?

Comment: You cannot transform layer CRS to another CRS in Leaflet. Whatever CRS you specify for map, all layers must natively have the same CRS. OSM layer has natively EPSG:3857, so it won't work when you set map CRS to EPSG4326.

Comment: So, I need to reproject my Images to EPSG:3857? Is that suggested? Is there not a way to reproject the map container? @TomazicM

Comment: No, Leaflet has no raster layer reprojection (unlike OpenLayers, which has no problems with that). All raster layers must be in the same CRS as map. So if you have tile layer in  EPSG:3857 and image in EPSG:4326, you will have to reproject the image for use with that tile layer.